# How to change multiple properties of an object at once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, mongoose

I'm trying to update a document using mongoose. And I would like to update multiple properties at once. I've tried using the spread operator to clone the document and override the properties that need to be updated with user input, but it returned error `document.save is not a function`. I kind of understand why it throws the errors. Because it's not the same object, it's just a clone so it doesn't have `save` method. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
So my question is: is there a way to update the object like with spread operator?

My code:

```
router.put("/posts/update", (req, res)=>{
    const {id, updatedFields} = req.body;
    Post.findById(id).exec((err, post)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        post = {...post, updatedFields};
        post.save();
        res.json(post);
    })
});
```

Comment: Maybe try -> `Object.assign(post, updateFields)`

Comment: Just a note:  I'm not a mongoose expert.  But doing this looks like a very bad security issue.  What if somebody sent ->  `{"post": "return fs.readFileSync(\"rootpassword.txt\")"}` or something similar.

Comment: Currently, I'm just learning how to male a react app with nodejs. I don't knpw anything about security except using Helmetjs middlewares which I think it is not at all enough. I shall learn security after I get a good knowledge of nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`

```
post= Object.assign(post, updatedFields);
```

The assign function can take as many arguments as you would like. Each argument is applied on the leftmost, from left to right. So if multiple arguments hold the same property, its value would be the one from the right.

Comment: Empty {} not getting assigned :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assing` it'll not change object reference.

I would suggest instate of throwing err, send the response with some status code.

```
router.put("/posts/update", (req, res) => {
    const {
        id,
        updatedFields
    } = req.body;
    Post.findById(id).exec((err, post) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).json({err, msg: 'Some msg'});
        post = Object.assign(post, updatedFields);
        post.save();
        res.json(post);
    })
});
```